# WatchViewStub on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, moto-360

I know this question has been answered many times on here but I still can't seem to fix my problem. I am trying to create an application that reads the users heart rate and sends that information to the phone. My problem is that I have implemented a `WatchViewStub` but every time I run the program it keeps giving me a `NullPointerException` `on a null object reference`. I really can't seem to figure out why this is giving me such error. Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Error is coming from line 31 which is:

```
stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
```

HeartRateWearActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.round_activity_heart_rate);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            timeStampTxt = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.timeStampTxt);
            hrTxt = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.hrTxt);

            measureBtn = (Button) stub.findViewById(R.id.measureBtn);
            measureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (!toggle) {
                        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SensorService.class));
                        toggle = true;
                    } else {
                        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SensorService.class));
                        toggle = false;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
    this.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.Broadcast"));
}
```

round_activity_heart_rate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HeartRateWearActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear_round"
android:id="@+id/r_bg"
android:background="#ED2D50">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hrTxt"
    android:textSize="80dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="bpm"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/hrTxt"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/hrTxt"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/hrTxt" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="last update"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hrTxt"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="7:15"
    android:id="@+id/timeStampTxt"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/measureBtn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeStampTxt"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:checked="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error from Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.health/com.example.user.health.HeartRateWearActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub$OnLayoutInflatedListener)' on a null object reference

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub$OnLayoutInflatedListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.user.health.HeartRateWearActivity.onCreate(HeartRateWearActivity.java:31)
```

Comment: Which is the line no 31 ?

Comment: Line 31 is - stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {

Comment: Could you post your relevant `XML` code here.

Comment: Of course, just done it.

Comment: May be problem with this `measureBtn = (Button) stub.findViewById(R.id.measureBtn);` change `Button` to `Switch`.

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);` is coming back as null because you don't have `@+id/watch_view_stub` in your layout

Comment: Or may be where you defined whtch view stub in xml ?

Comment: @cricket_007 Would you mind telling me where exaclty would I add "`@+id/watch_view_stub`"?

Comment: @underscore_  Add it as root tag in your xml.

Comment: You are using the wrong layout file. Where is the `android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub` XML tag?

Comment: Check this sample project for reference. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchViewStub

Comment: Right, that's under another xml file called `activiy_heart_rate.xml`.